# Как сделать такой адаптив как здесь?

Tags: html, css

[image: Изображение]

Как можно реализовать данный перенос строк внутри одной ссылки как на картинке?

Comment: А в чем проблема? ограничьте ссылку  или ее контейнер по ширине, она и перенесется.

Comment: она тогда перенесется полностью, а нужно по словам.

Comment: вообще-то, если в тексте есть пробелы/разрывы, то по словам и будет. Но если их нет, то см. ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Вот, выбирайте

```css
div {
  background: wheat;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.breakall a {
  word-break: break-all;
}

.breakword a {
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div>aaaaaaaaaaaaa > bbbb bbbbbbbbb bb > cccccccccccc ccccccc > <a href="#">dddddddd ddddd dddddddddddd dddd ddddddddddd</a></div>

<div class="breakall">aaaaaaaaaaaaa > bbbb bbbbbbbbb bb > cccccccccccc ccccccc > <a href="#">eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</a></div>

<div class="breakword">aaaaaaaaaaaaa > bbbb bbbbbbbbb bb > cccccccccccc ccccccc > <a href="#">eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</a></div>
```